# What format do we need to use to store data in db.Time?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a database with SQLAlchemy and SQLite. I have some database models and one of them needs a time. Not the time-of-the-day sort of time but like when-you-study-for-10-minutes sort of time. What format can we store in db.Time?
Code:

```
time = db.Column(db.Time, nullable=False)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a "time interval"? "15 minutes" or "28 days"?

Comment: Yeah i think something like that

Comment: I just searched up time intervals and I think that's what I need. Can you add your answer below so I can say that the question has been answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a "time interval". SQLite doesn't have that. In fact, [it doesn't have a time type at all](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype). So use whatever you want.

I would suggest storing the number of seconds in the interval as an integer. For "15 minutes" you would store 900.

[SQLAlchemy does have an Interval type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Interval) for storing datetime.timedelta objects which you could try. The docs say "*the value is stored as a date which is relative to the “epoch” (Jan. 1, 1970)*" which I think is just a fancy way to say they'll store the number of seconds.